# How to output first line of curl result in a file with bash script

Tags: bash, curl, grep

I want to read a file of urls, curl each url and only get the first line which contains the HTTP code. I am running under Windows 10 inside Cmder.

```
#!/bin/bash
input="urls.csv"
truncate -s 0 dest.csv
while IFS= read -r var
do
    result= `curl -I ${var%$'\r'} | grep HTTP $result`
echo "$var $result" >> dest.csv
done < "$input"
```

however the output file is empty, thank you

Comment: Are you getting a pile of errors as well?

Comment: @thatotherguy no i don't see error, I am running inside Cmder under Windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `urls.csv` is just a simple list of URLs and you're working on a linux system (or any system which has `/dev/null`), following command will send HEAD requests to each URL and output them next to HTTP response codes.

```
sed 's/^/url = /; s/\r\?$/\n-o \/dev\/null/' urls.csv |
curl -s -K- -w '%{http_code} %{url_effective}\n' -I >outfile
```

see [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for further information.

Comment: Hi thank you, I didn't manage to make it run in Cmder Windows 10, but it ran ok on Linux, now can you tell me how to output the HTTP code + the url in a file? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In reply to your query on outputting the HTTP code, this is given in the second line of the header. You may get this by:

```
export IFS=$; # This is required to stop everything coming out on one line!
curl -i <domain> | head -n 2
```